# Need further assistance with lifting my Stack Overflow question ban

Tags: support, post-ban

My account was question banned about 2 weeks ago. Since then, I've edited all my questions in order to get an upvote and get out of the post-ban, but none of my questions have been upvoted, and my account's status has remained the same.

I understand I didn't help my situation by deleting downvoted questions, but I want to improve.

Is there any further action I can take besides editing and flagging?

Can I directly contact the moderators to show them I can properly form a question?

Comment: Have you edited and undeleted your downvoted questions?

Comment: I've undeleted this one that the Roomba cleaned up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53357218/ruby-how-to-post-form-data-onto-a-website-using-net-http in case you wanted to work on that as well. This question would need a little work to be brought on topic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52460083/19679 and this deleted question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52894233/ruby-fake-access-point-not-showing-up-as-a-wireless-network is an exact duplicate of one you had migrated from Super User, so I don't know what could be done there.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks, but how would I bring attention to those questions once I've edited them?

Comment: *Can I directly contact the moderators to show them I can properly form a question?* I'm a bit worried as the FAQ on this topic says [*Moderators cannot lift the ban, so don't bother to ask*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). That FAQ post is your life-line. You should know it by heart if you really plan on lifting your quality-ban

Comment: Do know that significant edits of a post *bump* it to the top of the question list. Make sure that edit makes the post substantial better. Those who can vote get pretty irritated if the same post is edited (and therefor bumped) 10 times to replace a comma ...

Comment: Another thing worth noting is that editing your questions does not guarantee a lift of the question ban; it may be that there is no practicable solution other than to wait out your six months.  In general, reading the linked question you get when you try to post will tell you all that you need to know.  Patience is a huge factor.

Comment: Looks like a lot of your questions are "I want to do X in Ruby. How do I do it?" You have to search and research. If you have, add it--I don't mean "I've researched but I found nothing." I mean "I searched for "[some search query]" and "[some related query]" and I found information about [some blog post], but it didn't have any code or link me to any examples, and I heard about [some related framework] but I don't think it helps solve my problem because [reasons]". It not only shows good will on your part, it can help prevent answerers from wasting their time suggesting things you researched.

Comment: Two remaining deleted questions, score <= 0: ([1](//stackoverflow.com/q/52894233) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/52460083))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The downvoted questions I can see...

> [I want to use net\http to POST form data onto a website. I know there are libraries like mechanize that can ease the process, but I'm wondering if there's a way I can do the same with net/http.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53357218/ruby-how-to-post-form-data-onto-a-website-using-net-http)

Ideally you would work on this solution first before asking the question, the question would then say. I've written this code using net/http and it does this, but I expected it to do that instead. I.e. an attempt at the problem so we can see where and why you're stuck, otherwise what do you want us to say as an answer? Here's some code using mechanize, I've tried to implement this same solution using net/http but I got stuck here would likely work too.

> [I'm trying to learn about the Win32api for Ruby, and I've come across the HWND type in different functions such as the MessageBox function. What does the HWND type do, and what data type does it belong to; pointer, integer, or long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53219422/what-data-type-does-hwnd-type-belong-to)

What are you trying to do. Are you trying to display a MessageBox? Have you written some code to do so that doesn't display a message box? If so show that code so we can see where you've gone wrong?

> [I'm trying to make a Ruby script which to connect WiFi, and look for other WiFi networks. I wonder if there's a way, to connect to wifi using raw sockets perhaps, or the Net series of gems, but I don't know where to start, can anyone help me with this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050463/is-there-a-way-that-can-connect-to-a-wifi-network-using-ruby)

You're basically asking us to find something, a gem, for you. We're not an alternative to a search engine here. If you can't find a library perhaps you can write your own solution using some underlying capability of the platform. If you get stuck on that, we can probably help.

You need to concentrate on your questions being more [specific programming problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) rather than where do I start if I want to do X, they usually tend not to fly well.

Moderators are unlikely to help much, there's no reason to suppose they will be experts in the topics you're asking about.

Go through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) especially the sections on [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and adjust your questions accordingly, which may well mean doing more research first so that you have actual practical problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but for the second question you brought up; I was just asking what category the HWND type fell under. Anyways, thanks for bringing up what I need to work on!